Is it ok to say "when Moshiach comes, we will find out who is right" to someone of a different religion?
The reason I ask is because it might come across as you are not sure about your Emunah, and it might be construed that you are saying their religion could be right.
These might be problems. It might also be fine, especially in a proper context - fostering a goodwill conversation. As we know, it's not a good idea to back people into a wall, or tell them they are wrong. It's not conducive to a productive, open minded conversation, and risks turning things into a full blown debate (something we are known to avoid).

So, here's an example:

A Rabbi and a Minister are on a panel discussing religion to the public. In order to not come across as closed minded, or arrogant, and to inject a bit of humour and goodwill, the Rabbi says "...so, when the Messiah comes, if turns out to be your guy, I would happily admit I am wrong, and either way I'm sure we both look forward to the day when God's name is known by the whole world and we all have an opportunity to get close to Him"


Edit: The reason why I think this is not opinion based is because I can imagine that there would be some halachot that would assist in giving a fact based answer. The only issue would be if those halachot could be interpreted in multiple ways without Rishonic or Acharonic support. 
Therefore, it would also be fact-based to bring examples. I could bring Ben Shapiro, for example, who said something very similar to what I wrote in the example above, when asked why he is not a Christian, at a talk at a university. He said effectively what Shalom said in his comment below, then added a throw away "look, when Moshiach does come, we will see who is right, and if it wasn't me, I'll happily admit I was wrong" (I'll try to find the exact quote)
Is that a good precedent? He is a learned Jew, but perhaps we have higher calibre examples, or even good solid examples from some of the many recorded discussions and debates with non-Jews over the millenia? As Yaacov Deane said, this is important, and worthy of a round table discussion (you never know when you might end up in a discussion with non-Jews about religion afterall, it's best to go in with knowledge!)
Given that there is a halacha tag, this already limits the question so people will not be on topic if they voice their personal opinions. I added the sources tag, and if anyone has any suggestions on tags to further limit it (should we make a maasim tag or is there one already?). 
Lastly, if anyone wishes to edit the question themselves to salvage it, feel free. I edited the example as well, to make it more hypothetical, as that will probably make the question easier to answer. Shkoyach

https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.18.21?lang=bi&with=all

@Sholom There he's not saying that he'll follow Baal, ch"v.

I appreciate your question, the subject is worthy of open, round table discussion. But, to be honest, Mi Yodeya doesn’t seem to be the correct forum for your question. It definitely lends itself to personal opinion rather than clear answer. And based on the site guidelines for what makes an appropriate and good question, in my opinion, it seems to fail. I would love to hear anyone else’s view about this.

@YaacovDeane if the question is closed based on personal opinion, that in itself with be useful knowledge to me :) VTC and let's see what happens!

"Good fences make good neighbors, we will agree to disagree on certain points that fundamentally make your faith yours, and mine mine." Hard stop.

Speaking commonly with a variety of abrahamic religious types is a norm for me. Typically we all believe in a coming or returning of a moshiach type. And Moshiach does commonly come up in conversation.
I try to stay in the ‘He who comes will come for us all’ realm. The example between the rabbi and minister is great! I sometimes say ‘no matter the specifics of the who/where/when/how - I will still raise my voice in praise.
Conceding to the unique correctness of HaShem is not an admission of incorrect belief. It is a show of faith.
Jeremiah 18 is commonly used to end disputes as disputations are incorrect.
Proverbs 18:6
A fools lips enter into contention.
Proverbs 13:10
Only by pride cometh contention.
In our own pride we believe we know. And after all - in the light of ‘Who is right?’ there is only 1 who is correct.
Job 40 helps one see how to align correctly with this idea. Jeremiah 18 proves our need to be willing to be whatever HaShem desires us to be.

Could you expound more how your sources help answer the original question? For example, could you add the details whether something is lost in the answer of the Rabbi? Please quote the sources, and use hyperlinks to Sefaria.org. Thanks!

Hi Y DJ - I don’t understand fully what you are asking. What do you mean by “lost in the answer of the Rabbi”?

The OP modified the question. He now states what he feels is missing. I feel that your answer is still applicable, however, in Judaism we distinguish between arguments, as in Pirkei Avot 5:17: Every dispute that is for the sake of Heaven, will in the end endure; But one that is not for the sake of Heaven, will not endure. Disputes between religions can easily be turned into disputes over power, which is not going to bring any truth to the disputants.

I agree with this viewpoint as well. Thank you for clarifying for me. I am still quite new to this environment.
